# Why Content Path cannot be used to sort a view?

Tags: 7, views

Using *Views* with Drupal **7**, how can I use the *content path* to sort a result table?

I have node *title*, *created date* and *path* as fields for a view.
The first two fields have the checkbox to make them sorting options in the display settings, but the *node path* field doesn't.

Comment: Are you trying to sort by node path, i.e. node/123, node/124, or by URL aliases, i.e. content/page-title-one, content/page-title-two?

Comment: good question ;) by url aliases

Comment: Well, a quick Google search turned up http://drupal.org/project/views_url_alias. Probably URL aliases do not have Views sort handlers included in Views 7.x. It would be trivial to write one, so hopefully this module has already done so.

Answer (score 0):

*Node path* is not a field from DB table. It is calculated dynamically.

In views you can only sort if a sorting can be applied to the underlying SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want get results with URL. So you can follow screens to do that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to sort on something that isn't a DB field. Instead, you have to associate it with something else that is sortable. For example, if your URL aliases map to the node's NID, you could put them both in the same column, exclude the NID from the view, and sort on that.